# How can I transfer RAM from one account to another?

Tags: ram, eosjs

I have account with some kilobytes of RAM and I need transfer a part of the RAM to another account. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

From the [mainnet governance repository](https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/governance/blob/master/eosio.system/eosio.system-buyrambytes-rc.md):

> {{buyer}} acknowledges that RAM is non-transferable.

What you can do to transfer RAM to someone is simply buying more RAM and assigning the other account as the receiver of the RAM purchase. This is one of the parameters of the `buyram` action, and depending on what tool/wallet you use to interact with the system contract, you'll be able to specify it or not. Logically if you buy more RAM to send to that other account, and you want it to come from your own RAM instead of your EOS balance, then it would make sense for you to then sell some of your RAM to recover the EOS you spent buying RAM for the other account. It's important to keep in mind that this will cost you the fees to buy and sell RAM.